# Combine all boolean response of JSON objects to one with Jq

Tags: json, jq

i have huge json data, in every object has download_able and playable attribute which is boolean type.

So i try to compare each other every objects attribute and get only one response.

`jq '.result[].downlaodable or .result[].playable'` response me like that

```
true
true
true
```

I want to compare these response again and i have to get one response.

But i can't do that. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but I think you want to do a boolean `or` of the results you get with your existing jq program. This is how you'd do it:

`jq '[.result[].downlaodable or .result[].playable] | any'`

This should just output: `true`

Comment: Hi @Santiago thanks for reply,
I found solution my question. Such as yours but i need to catch false.

`[ (.result[].downlaodable or .result[].playable) ] | @json | contains("false")`

Comment: If you want to know if all the results are true, you can just use `all` instead of `any` on the script I provided you.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using all now :)